# Initialize abstract class field in child's constructor

Tags: inheritance, kotlin

I have abstract class A with some field

```
public abstract class A {
    var name: String = "Empty name"
}
```

and want to inherit it

```
public class B(name: String) : A() {
    init {
        this.name = name
    }
}
```

Is there a way for not to create an init block and do one-line init of `name` like `class B(::name: String)`?

Comment: There's no need to override, but simply to init

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to do that for a property which is not declared in the parent class [primary constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors).

But you can transform your example adding a primary constructor:

```
public abstract class A(var name: String = "Empty name")

public class B(name: String) : A(name)
```

Comment: It looks strange to have access for creating fields in constructor and no access to init existing

Answer (score 2):

You can use `override` annotation

```
abstract class A {
    open val name: String = "Empty name"
}

class B(override val name: String) : A()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `name` `abstract` or `open` and then `override` it in `B`. e.g.:

```
public abstract class A {
    open var name: String = "Empty name"
}
public class B(name: String) : A() {
    override var name: String = name
}
```

It isn't exactly "in" the constructor but it might meet your needs.